# Why do we need a (read) lock when reading a value in a concurrent environment?

Tags: java, concurrency

Assuming the following class:

```java
public class Counter {
    private long val;
    private final ReadWriteLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public Counter(long val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void increment() {
        try {
            reentrantLock.writeLock().lock();
            val++;
        } finally {
            reentrantLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public long getVal() {
        try {
            reentrantLock.readLock().lock();
            return this.val;
        } finally {
            reentrantLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Ignoring that we could use `AtomicLong`, what bad things could happen when we read without a lock and why are these things happening.

My assumptions:

1. Not the latest value (a new writer thread could update the value +1 in the moment we read), so we would be at least one value behind
2. Some garbage in-between writes value (can that happen in java)

Another assumption:

- There's no risk of not seeing any writer value, since the WriteLock enforces memory barriers which will flush the value to main memory

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: If something can write in a memory cell at any time, then you will always need a lock in a concurrent environment. If it is a read only memory cell, then it is pretty much useless to add a lock. This is one of the race conditions you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Amdahl's_law_and_Gustafson's_law)

Comment: You have read locks, so that multiple threads can read at the same time, but read locks also wait for write locks, so only one thread at a time can write, and no reading occurs while a writer is mutating values. 
 So, #2, plus the performance improvement that an explicitly read-only lock lets you have multi-threaded reads. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

Comment: Acquiring of the lock should be done outside of the try-block. Because it could fail for whatever reason and then one should not true to unlock it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad thing that can (in theory) happen is if readers don't use the read locks is that they could see a stale value of the counter; i.e. a value that is NOT the latest value written by a writer.

In Java, primitive locks and `Lock` classes have two functions:

1. The provide mutual exclusion.
2. They provide threads with certain guarantees about visibility of values in shared variables.

Without the visibility guarantees provided by *correct* use of locks (and some other things), changes made by one thread may not be visible to another thread.

---

Unfortunately, while there is no guarantee that that one thread won't see the correct value, there is no guarantee that it will see an incorrect one either.  The actual behavior depends on a number of different factors that are difficult to analyze ... and are implementation and platform dependent.  So *demonstrating* that a thread can see stale values can be difficult.  Likewise, you cannot **prove** that a program doesn't have that kind of flaw by testing it.  And if a program *does* have this kind of flaw, it is likely to be hard to reproduce ... especially when you are using a debugger.

---

> Not the latest value (a new writer thread could update the value +1 in the moment we read), so we would be at least one value behind.

In fact, the reader could see a value that many updates behind ... or even the initial value of `val`.

> Some garbage in-between writes value (can that happen in java)

This is also possible. The JMM treats a `long` or a `double` as two separate memory cells, so an reader that doesn't use locks could see a high word from one value and a low word from a different value.

> There's no risk of not seeing any writer value, since the WriteLock enforces memory barriers which will flush the value to main memory.

This is incorrect from two respects:

1. That is an implementation detail.  The JMM says nothing about memory barriers, and neither do the relevant javadocs.
2. In fact if the reader is not using a read lock, the JIT compiler *might* emit code that caches the value of `val` in a register ... and not bother to re-read it from main memory in all circumstances.

   Note that this is *also* an implementation detail.  But this is a behavior that is *permitted* by the JMM.  When the reader doesn't use the lock, there will be no *happens before* relation between the write and the subsequent read.  With out that relation, the code doesn't need to meet the visibility guarantee.

Comment: Last thing i wonder: would volatile make the readlock redundant? It also makes sure all threads have the latest value

Comment: Individual reads and writes to a `volatile long` or `double` are atomic (JLS 17.7).  However the increment operator (`++`) consists of a read and a write and is therefore not atomic.  So if you use a `volatile long` or `volatile int`, for `val`, the readers don't need a lock, but the writers (still) do need a lock.

Comment: Lock provides another very important guarantee and that is ordering. A lock acquire provides acquire semantics and a lock release provides release semantics. Without these semantics, locks are pretty useless. For more information check roach motel semantics.

Comment: The current JMM doesn't say anything about fences but they are a part of the JVM. The documentation about fences is there https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html.  Currently it is an ugly wart, but work is in progress to provide an updated JMM that does include the fences and the relaxed access modes like opaque/acquire-release. https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3360568

Comment: The phrase 'last written values' seems to imply that the loads/stores are respecting the real time order of requests. The only guarantee that the JMM makes is that a reads needs to see the most recent write before it in the happens-before order. But reads/writes are allowed to be skewed as long as the PO isn't violated. So if you want to educate @Regyn I would rephrase your text because currently it is misleading.

Comment: If and when those developments make it into the actual published JLS, then we can change the way that we describe that the specs say.  As for your other comment, you are reading far to much into those three words.  As always, please feel free to write your own Answer if you think you can do a better job.